# AS3 : Load image from xml

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I try to load images from xml.
My script is on frame 1.

```
var fichierXML:URLRequest = new URLRequest("datas.xml");

//Chargement du fichier
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
loader.load(fichierXML);

//Traitement des données
function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
//Récupération des données du fichier XML
var xml:XML = new XML(e.target.data); 

//Extraction des données généralistes
var Name:XMLList = xml.list.name; 
var pictureProfilOriginal:XMLList = xml.list.pictureProfilOriginal; 
var pictureProfil:XMLList = xml.list.pictureProfil; 
var totalView:XMLList = xml.list.totalView; 
var totalLoves:XMLList = xml.list.totalLoves; 

loadImage(image01, "crop_image_1.jpg");
}

function loadImage(mc:MovieClip, urlReq:String):void {      
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
mc.addChild(loader);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doneLoad);
// start loading
loader.load(new URLRequest(urlReq));
}

function doneLoad(e:Event):void {
e.target.loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doneLoad);

// smoothing the bitmap
var bit:Bitmap = e.target.content;
if(bit != null)
bit.smoothing = true;
}
```

When my clip "image01" is on frame 1, it load my image crop_image_1.jpg, but if my clip "image01" is on frame 2, i have this error :

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Il est impossible d'accéder à la propriété ou à la méthode d'une référence d'objet nul.
at Film_animation_fla::MainTimeline/loadImage()    [Film_animation_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:68]
at Film_animation_fla::MainTimeline/onLoaded()  [Film_animation_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:62]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

I begin with actionscript, maybe anyone have an idea to help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to use more than one frame if you can. The target movie clip being on frame 2 means that is does not exist when you are trying to add the child to it "mc.addChild(loader);".

If you really need two frames, extend the key frame of the image01 to start from frame 1, and if it's not empty hide the movie clip. You will have to show image01 again when you arrive at frame 2.